# Subquery With Yii Active Record

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

Is it possible to write sub queries with Yii active record?

I need to add a subquery in the FROM clause. Below is the SQL with the subquery but I want to specifically write it using Active Record.

In SQL, Policy has a many to many relationship with policy_vehicles.

SQL Query:

```
select * from (SELECT Name , GROUP_CONCAT(PV.VehicleId SEPARATOR ',') as VehicleIds 
FROM `policies` `t` 
LEFT JOIN policy_vehicles PV USING(PolicyId)
WHERE (Type IN ('C', 'E')) AND (Status='Active')
GROUP BY t.PolicyId 
) k where VehicleIds like '%1%' AND VehicleIds like '%2%'
```

This is how I want to use it in the Controller class:

```
$model = Policy::model();
$model->Status = array('Active');
$model->VehicleIds = array(1,2);
$model->Type = array('C', 'E');
$datas = $model->search()->getData();
print_r($datas);
```

Search function in the model:

```
public function search() {

    $joins = array();
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('Type', $this->Type);
    $criteria->compare('Status', $this->Status);

    array_push($joins, 'LEFT JOIN policy_vehicles PV USING(PolicyId)');
    $criteria->join = implode(' ', $joins);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Why yii2 in your tag?.....this is Yii1